# How can I know my current route in react-navigation 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am using this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html to access my navigation from any source, my file look as follow:

```
import { createRef } from 'react';

export const navigationRef = createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  return navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

export function goBack() {
  return navigationRef.current?.goBack();
}

export function getRootState() {
  return navigationRef.current?.getRootState();
}
```

This is perfect for my `@navigation/drawer`, which is outside my stack navigation.

Only one problem the last method is not synchronized and I want to have an active state on my item menu that is the current route.

How is that possible with react navigation 5?

Comment: Try this:
`navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName` ... it depends on the structure of your navigation ... so try to console.log `navigation.state`, and you will get to what you want...

Comment: Well, I can't. I am not using v4. In v5, I must use `useNavigation()` to access the navigation and because I am outside the stack navigator (I am into the DrawerContent of the drawer navigator and it wrap the stack navigator), then I can't access the `navigation` object this way. This is why I have linked this : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Comment: if you want to access `navigation` object inside a contentComponent of the Drawer:
You could try this: `this.props.descriptors.YourStackIdentifer.navigation` ... I mean `navigation` object is there in the props without the need to inject it using `useNavigation` or anything like that...

Comment: I use `<DrawerNavigator drawerContent={DrawerContent}><Stack.Navigator><ScreenList /></Stack.Navigator></DrawerNavigator>`, in order to use `useNavigation`, you **MUST** be in `<Stack.Navigator />` tree, but `DrawerContent` is not so it is not possible to use `useNavigation`. Also, `navigation` is not injected into DrawerContent.

Comment: I'm have same issues with you, i tried with `useNavigation()` and `useNavigationState()` but always have not latest state. Maybe you can try this way, i think currently only this way can achive [State Persistance](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/state-persistence/#!). By using AsyncStorage to get latest state or create a context provider to store the state when change update the context.

Comment: Please checkout the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005239/how-to-get-current-routename-in-react-navigation-drawer-drawer-compoenent/61329656#61329656

Answer (score 6):

I am using the following approach to get the current route name in react-navigation v5.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetstate

```
const {index, routes} = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetState();
const currentRoute = routes[index].name;
console.log('current screen', currentRoute);
```

Answer (score 3):

The NavigationContainer has onStateChange prop, useful for this case, check react-navigation docs [Screen Tracking for analytics](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking)  and if you need access without navigation prop see [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)

I share the code to get only active routeName

```js
function App(){
    const routeNameRef = React.useRef();
    // Gets the current screen from navigation state
    const getActiveRouteName = (state)=> {
        const route = state.routes[state?.index || 0];

        if (route.state) {
          // Dive into nested navigators
          return getActiveRouteName(route.state);
        }

        return route.name;
    };

    return (<NavigationContainer
    onStateChange={(state) => {
      if (!state) return;
      //@ts-ignore
      routeNameRef.current = getActiveRouteName(state);
    }}
    >
    ...
    </NavigationContainer>)
}
```

Comment: @kd12345 Sure, I do it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the current screen from a component you can also use this:

```
export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

    console.log(route.name);

    return (
        {...}
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get this from the navigationRef attached to the navigation container. Where navigationRef is a ref.

`export const navigationRef = React.createRef()`

and

```
<NavigationContainer
   ref={navigationRef} 
   >
  <Navigator />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then use:  `const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name` to get the current route name.

Alternatively in a functional component you can useRef `const navigationRef = React.useRef()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a util function called `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route)` which [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state) recommends.
BUT - it seems its working only for child screen, so I defined the following function to get the active route name:

```
const getCurrentRouteName = (navigation, route) => {
    if (route.state)
        return getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    return route.name;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. In navigationRef.js

```
let navigator;

export const setNavigator = (nav) => {
  navigator = nav;
};

export const getCurrentRoute = () => {
  const route = navigator.getCurrentRoute();
  return route.name;
};
```

This can be referred from any source like this

```
import { getCurrentRoute } from '../navigationRef';

const currentScene = getCurrentRoute();
```

Comment: My mistake, that line was not necessary. I've edited it out.